# React native stream audio from flash player

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to stream a local online radio from this link   [flash player streaming the radio link](http://westcoast.gm/wp-content/plugins/shout-stream/longffmp3.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstream.westcoast.gm:8002/;&title=West%20Coast%20Radio%2092.1&autoplay)

How can go about streaming the online radio in react native? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`react-native-audio-streaming`](https://github.com/tlenclos/react-native-audio-streaming). I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it should work for you. For SHOUTCast servers (which is what you're pointing to), add `;&type=mp3` to the end of the URL. So your stream URL would be: `http://stream.westcoast.gm:8002/;&type=mp3`.